# Greek Chi and Anointment

Tags: commentaries, oil, maseches-menachos, mincha-meal-offering, greek

In [Menachos 75a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.75a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and other places it says that meshicha, smearing of oil, on the רקיקים wafer-offerings, is done כמין כי יווני - like a greek letter chi. [Tosefos](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.75a?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Menachot.75a.10.1&lang2=bi&w2=Translations&lang3=en) there brings quite a
few explanations for what this anointment looks like.

> כמין כי. צייר בקונט' כמין טי"ת ובפירושי חומש פי' גימל ויש מפרישים כמין
> נון או כמין כ' ובערוך פירש דתניא בכריתות (דף ה:) המלכים מושחין כמין
> נזר והכהנים כמין כי יוונית פירוש יצק שמן על ראש [אהרן] ויורד אילך
> ואילך כמין שני מרגליות
> Like a (Hebrew) tet... like a gimel... like a nun or a chaf... And the Arukh explains... like a Greek chi [which is] like two legs descending here and here...

None of them seem to me to correspond to the [Greek chi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_(letter)) that I thought was well-known: Ⲭ, some kind of "x".
How does one understand this? Is it similar to "Well, Tosefos probably never saw an elephant!" kind of thing? Weren't there at least Christian theologians or some such in France who knew Greek? The Arukh is said to have been born in Rome!
Or were there other ways to make a chi?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118713/759

Comment: @Harel13 "two legs" - what is the alternative?

Comment: "like a tet" ktav ivri tet looks like an x enclosed in an o

Comment: I wonder if there is obfuscation around this because the chi was borrowed as one of the earliest Christian symbols.

Comment: I should amend my earlier comment: Tosefos is not guessing; they are simply quoting a bunch of earlier opinions. My question is really on them. And presumably they all have reasons for their opinions, but Tosefos doesn't tell us anything about those reasons.

Comment: @MichoelR "_'two legs' - what is the alternative_"? Maybe 'pearls', as [Sefaria's translation of Keritot 5b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Keritot.5b.24?lang=bi&lang2=en) gives it.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting this summary of the Tosafos [here](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/menachos/tosfos/mn-ts-075.htm) which adds an additional commentaries note demonstrating that others do read it like an 'Ⲭ'. It writes there:

> NOTE: [Rashi in Kerisus (5b DH k'Min)](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.5b.21?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Keritot.5b.21.2&lang2=bi) and the Rambam ([Hilchos Klei ha'Mikdash 1:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Vessels_of_the_Sanctuary_and_Those_who_Serve_Therein.1.9?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)) drew the form of an "X". Tif'eres Yisrael (ibid.) concludes like the Rambam.

So it could well be that Tosafos was just not familiar with Greek language, whilst people like Rashi and Rambam were more knowledgeable in this regard.

Although having said this, the summary in the same link does seem to interpret Tosafos' understanding in the same manner - i.e. that it did resemble the X formation:

> Explanation #4 (Aruch): A Beraisa in Kerisus (5b) teaches that kings they anoint (put the oil in a shape) like a crown, **and Kohanim Gedolim like a Greek Chai**. I.e. [Moshe] poured oil on Aharon's head, and **it descended in two directions, like two legs (coming out of the torso)**, and this is its form.

Comment: Didn't follow this: a V doesn't look like an X.

Comment: That second part is the Musaf Ha'Aruch and Tiferes Yisrael's understanding of the text.  According to the first part it resembled the Chi in that "[Moshe] poured oil on Aharon's head, and it descended in two directions, like two legs (coming out of the torso)"

Comment: I deleted the latter to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 1):

Consolidating my comments, the typical European Rishonic rabbi did not usually consult local Christian scholars to understand Jewish sources. A couple of examples were brought [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26897/secular-studies-in-the-rhineland-academies-of-the-11th-13th-centuries/120610#120610) about the Tosfot's lack of understanding of Greek. To that I would add this statement from [Rashi on Eruvin 65a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Eruvin.65a.10.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi&p2=Eruvin.65a.10&lang2=bi) (my translation):

> ""When distressed, one should not issue decisions" - I have looked over all of scripture and this is not in any of the texts and perhaps it is found in the Book of Ben Sira."

This verse does not appear in Ben Sira, neither the Greek nor the Hebrew versions (at least not those that we have today), yet the Greek Ben Sirach is part of the Catholic Bible and Rashi could have theoretically checked with local Christians. But he didn't.

About the Aruch, it is very likely that he did not know Greek. We find that the author of [Yosifon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josippon), who also lived in Italy, but about a century *prior* to the Aruch, did not know Greek, despite being very learned (see [Prof. David Flusser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Flusser)'s introduction to his edition of Yosifon, [pg. 23 and note 62](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=179888&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16431107884904892&pagenum=22)).

On the Aruch's commentary, it is noted [here](https://www.machonso.org/hamaayan/?gilayon=46&id=1395#_ftnref10) that the Kohut edition of the Aruch brings different manuscripts with different drawn interpretations of which Greek letter the Aruch may have meant, which means it is unclear what he was referring to.

[Here](https://www.academia.edu/39347723/%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95_-_%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94) it is suggested that the Aruch was actually referring to a Latin C but for some reason referred to it as Greek. I'm afraid I did not quite understand the rationale.

Lastly, on your translation of the Tosfot - as @TamirEvan already pointed out in the comments, it turns out that the [quoted Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HeArukh%2C_Letter_Kaf.93?vhe=Sefer_HeArukh,_Lublin_1883&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) was referring to this phrase in [Keritot 5b and Horayot 12a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Keritot.5b.24?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&p2=Horayot.12a.7&lang2=bi):

> "The Sages taught in a baraita: The verse states: “It is like the precious oil upon the head descending upon the beard; the beard of Aaron, that descends upon the collar of his garments” (Psalms 133:2). Two drops of anointing oil **shaped like pearls** hung from Aaron’s beard."

These pearls are the מרגליות.

Comment: How do you draw pearls?

Comment: @MichoelR I believe he meant that the the *trail* of the oil that eventually leads off to two droplets that look like pearls should be shaped like a כי, whatever that's supposed to mean (see some suggestions above).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is asking why Tosefot don't know what a Chi is. But I would like to expand your question and argue that not only to Tosefot not know what a Chi is, but they don't know what a Paleo-Hebrew Tau  ( ת in Ashurit) looks like.

As others have mentioned the anointing of the bread is similar to the anointing of the priests brought down by the Rambam.

[Klei Hamikdash - Chapter 1:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008226/jewish/Klei-Hamikdash-Chapter-1.htm)

> How was the High Priest anointed? The oil should be poured on his head
> and applied between his eyes in the form of the Greek letter chi,30
> like this C as [Leviticus 8:12] states: "And he poured the anointing
> oil on Aaron's head and anointed him to sanctify him." The kings of
> the Davidic dynasty are anointed [with the oil] spread as a crown on
> their foreheads.31 They should not be anointed on other places [on
> their bodies], nor should one use an excessive amount of oil.
>
> ‏כֵּיצַד מוֹשְׁחִין אֶת הַכֹּהֵן. צָק אֶת הַשֶּׁמֶן עַל רֹאשׁוֹ
> וְסָךְ מִמֶּנּוּ עַל גַּבֵּי עֵינָיו כְּמִין כִּי יְוָנִית כָּזֶה X
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא ח יב) "וַיִּצֹק מִשֶּׁמֶן הַמִּשְׁחָה עַל רֹאשׁ
> אַהֲרֹן וַיִּמְשַׁח אֹתוֹ לְקַדְּשׁוֹ". וּמַלְכֵי בֵּית דָּוִד
> מוֹשְׁחִין אוֹתָן כְּמִין נֵזֶר עַל רֹאשׁוֹ. וְלֹא יִמְשַׁח
> בִּמְקוֹמוֹת אֲחֵרוֹת וְלֹא יַרְבֶּה בְּשֶׁמֶן:

All of these quotes seem to have a precedent in Tanakh in which Ezekiel has a vision in which people to be spared are marked with a Tau. Since Ezekiel is one of the more priestly prophets it makes sense to use a symbol that the priests would be familiar with and that would have some religious meaning.

Ezekiel 9:4

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהֹוָה֙ אֵלָ֔ו עֲבֹר֙ בְּת֣וֹךְ הָעִ֔יר בְּת֖וֹךְ
> יְרוּשָׁלָ֑͏ִם וְהִתְוִ֨יתָ **תָּ֜ו** עַל־מִצְח֣וֹת הָאֲנָשִׁ֗ים
> הַנֶּֽאֱנָחִים֙ וְהַנֶּ֣אֱנָקִ֔ים עַ֚ל כׇּל־הַתּ֣וֹעֵב֔וֹת
> הַֽנַּעֲשׂ֖וֹת בְּתוֹכָֽהּ׃ and the LORD said to him, “Pass through
> the city, through Jerusalem, and put a mark on the foreheads of the
> men who moan and groan because of all the abominations that are
> committed in it.”

However, marking someone with a Tau doesn't make much sense because we don't see the shape of ת being used anywhere else. And clearly the mark is supposed to have some religious significance. But my argument is that the mark of Tau is actually a Paleo Hebrew Tau that is shaped like an X

[image]

This same X symbol is used to anoint new priests, and the wafer offering. So I believe that once Paleo Hebrew fell out of use the Rabbis started substituting the Greek Chi to describe the X symbol, not realizing we used to have a letter in our Aleph Bet that already had that symbol.

So to answer your question: Knowledge gets lost, and it's rarely restored. Even when we discover how things used to be we often ignore it and do things the way it makes sense to us now. With that logic in mind it doesn't come as a surprise that when the Gemara wants to describe what the X shape looks like they use a Greek example since most Jews at that time would not know that a Paleo Hebrew Tau () looks like an X. Move forward some centuries and Tosefot's convoluted listing of possible examples make even more sense.

Comment: except ktav ivri was still used at the time of the gemara

Comment: Used in the times of the Gemara? I thought the last resurgence of ivri died with the Bar Kochba revolt

Comment: A nice interpretation of Yechezkel to be sure, but not new (sorry...). I've seen missionaries use this argument for years as "proof" that the prophetic formula of the crucifixion of Jesus is hidden within paleo-Hebrew. And yes, they do refer to this verse in Yechezkel.

Comment: Interesting, but I think this has way too much Original Research to be useful as a response to my question on Tosefos.

Comment: @Harel13 It's unfortunate that Christians are better about accepting the archeological record and its implications than we are. I also noticed when I was trying to get pictures of Paleo Hebrew that the vast majority of websites that come up first are weird Christian/Messianic websites. But unlike you I'm not going to judge the merits of the argument based solely on which religion the arguer happens to have.

Also I didn't say anywhere that my interpretation of Yehezkel was new. It's not new. Anyone who knows what the Paleo Hebrew alphabet looks like can easily draw the same conclusion I did.

Comment: @MichoelR So my argument that as things get lost they get even more lost/convoluted as time goes on isn't useful?

Comment: I wasn't judging the merits of the argument. I simply thought you were introducing it as your own since you wrote "But my argument". I see I was mistaken, and I'm sorry.

Comment: @Aaron It might be useful. I do think that the whole suggestion about tav is an independent suggestion, not relevant to drawing conclusions about Tosefos. As I said, they were simplying compiling suggestions they had heard, not explaining anyone's reasoning.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you. I should clarify. By saying it's my argument I mean it makes the most sense to me given all the evidence available, and so this is what I choose to believe about it right now. If tomorrow irrefutable evidence is found that Paleo Hebrew was never used by the Jews of Israel before the Babylonian expulsion then I would change my argument

Comment: @MichoelR Maybe I can add a more relevant connection. It's interesting to me that Tosefot chose to lead by saying that Chi looks like Tet. If you look at the Paleo Hebrew, the difference between Tet and Tau is very minor. Tet  is just a Tau  with a circle around it. So it's still an X, just an X with an additional circle.

Comment: @Aaron It would have been good if someone then had talked about the old Ivri script. It isn't clear to me that the Rishonim had seen it at all, though they had heard of it in the gemara.

Comment: @MichoelR Ramban, if I'm not mistaken, found an ancient Shekel when he was in Eretz Yisrael and it had Ivri on it. If I remember correctly, he consulted local Samaritans on how to read the coin, because they used and still use a form of Ivri.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you, Harel. But looking at Aaron's chart above, I can't tell if that would help? Looks like there are a lot of variants. "consulted local Samaritans". I wonder, btw, if Tosefos actually had access to real Christian scholars. It was the Dark Ages. Maybe you'd need to travel to a monastery, not just ask the local priest.

Comment: @MichoelR the "Dark Ages" weren't quite as dark as most people think, but you are correct that sometimes the local priest was not very knowledgeable. However, I'm pretty sure most of them knew how to read a Bible, which means that they knew Latin, at the very least. Sometimes Greek as well.